# UIWebview detect form text change

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, uikeyboard

I'm wondering if there is any good way to essentially apply `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`  to forms in a webview.

The result would be reacting to every typed/deleted letter in a web form.

Right now I'm using a timer that fires every .1 seconds to check the but it's not a very good solution and causes some bad behavior that appears to lock up the ability to call any other Javascript evalutations..

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this would be to "inject" some javascript code into the page, that would attempt navigation whenever the event you are interested in happens.
You'd catch and cancel that Navigation on the UIWebView, and use the navigation event as your event handler (possibly passing data in the url itself).

The series of events will be like this:

1. Event (e.g. change of value in a field) fires in JS.
2. Injected code Navigates to a certain (bogus) url.
3. Your app's Obj-C code will (listen to and) receive a navigation event. your code will check the url and find it is the one expected by the event. You can pass additional event data on the url itself.
4. The app code will cancel the navigation, so nothing actually changes on the page
5. Your app will react in whatever way you want to that event.

You didn't mention if you had control over the content of the web pages, so I'm not going into details on how to inject that javascript code. Let me know if that's something you want described.

I have been successful in augmenting/changing many DOM events, without actually owning the web pages that my UIWebView is navigating to, essentially giving the user a different experience when browsing these pages through my app than through a regular mobile browser.

hope that helps.
P.S. there might be an easier way using PhoneGap. I would be interested to know if that can shorten things.